# Inline SVG Animation Capabilities

Tags: animation, svg

I'm wondering [if this pen is possible](https://codepen.io/maaarj/pen/gmNeXd) to be created by inline SVG animation (SMIL)—without CSS or any javascript. Specifically interested in making the blur and undulation of the glowing circle, and the randomized floating energy particles that fade in and fade out in opacity very naturally. Please help!

Kept paring back to the below, but it's way less sophisticated :(

```
<g id="particle1">
<animateTransform
attributeName="transform"
type="translate"
values="0 0; -10 0; 0 0; 10 0"
dur="3s"
repeatCount="indefinite"/>
<g>
  <circle cx="100" cy="200" r="2.5" fill="#899dff">
    <animateTransform
    attributeName="transform"
    type="translate"
    from="0 0"
    to="0 -200"
    dur="3s"
    repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    <animate attributeName="opacity"
        from="1" to="0" dur="3s"
        repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </circle>
</g>
</g>

<g id="particle2">
<animateTransform
attributeName="transform"
type="translate"
values="0 0; 15 0; 0 0; -20 0"
dur="3s"
repeatCount="indefinite"/>
<g>
  <circle cx="100" cy="200" r="2.5" fill="#899dff">
    <animateTransform
    attributeName="transform"
    type="translate"
    from="25 30"
    to="25 -200"
    dur="3s"
    repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    <animate attributeName="opacity"
        from="0" to="1" dur="3s"
        repeatCount="indefinite"
        begin="2s"/>
  </circle>
 </g>
 </g>
```

Comment: The pen uses SCSS, not CSS. And from that it uses function `random()`. There is no random number generator you can access from declarative SVG code. Everything else is possible. Tip: you have to animate [blur filters](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/filters.html#feGaussianBlurElement)

Answer (score 1):

My earlier comment said there was no random number generator in SVG - well, that is not completely true. There is a pseudo-random number generator involved in the [`<feTurbulence>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/filters.html#feTurbulenceElement) filter (Note the `seed` you have to set). And you can use it, with a bit of creative tweaking, to produce twinkling stars. I haven't found a variant that twinkles the stars individually, but that is something also the original didn't achieve.

So, here is a partial answer. It doesn't recreate the whole pen, but only the twinkling pseudo-random stars.

The larger the `baseFrequency` is, the more stars you get, but at the same time you'll have to adapt the last number of the `<feColorMatrix>` value. It's trial and error. For me, this seemed to work:

```
baseFrequency="0.04" => values="0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.6 0 0 0 10 -7.8"
baseFrequency="0.1" => values="0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.6 0 0 0 10 -6.7"
```

The color is also defined via the color matrix. The fifth number defines the red channel: 0 equals 0, 1 equals 255. The tenth number is the greeen channel, the fifteenth the blue. My stars have a coloration of `rgb(255, 0, 153)`.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" height="500" width="100%">
  <defs>
    <filter id="twinkle" style="color-interpolation-filters:sRGB">
      <feTurbulence stitchTiles="stitch" seed="500" type="fractalNoise" numOctaves="2" baseFrequency="0.1" />
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2" />
      <feColorMatrix result="blob" values="0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.6 0 0 0 10 -6.7" />
      <feGaussianBlur result="blur" stdDeviation="2" />
      <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode in="blob" />
        <feMergeNode in="blur" />
        <feMergeNode in="blur" />
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <rect height="100%" width="100%" />
  <g id="field" >
    <rect style="filter:url(#twinkle)" height="500" width="100%">
      <animate attributeName="opacity" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite"
               keyTimes="0;0.5;1" values="0.3;0.8;0.3" keySplines=".5 0 .4 1;.6 0 .5 1" />
      <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="translate" dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite"
               from="0 0" to="0 -500" />
    </rect>
  </g>
  <use xlink:href="#field" y="500" />
</svg>
```

Comment: thank you @ccprog — really appreciate your help \(^-^)/